# Java error: “incompatible types” message. Converting to type int from type Coin

Tags: java

So I have this code here

```
    CoinBag<Coin> bag = new CoinBag<>();
    int choice = -1;

    do {
        System.out.println("[1] To add a new item to the bag");
        System.out.println("[2] To print bag contents");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        choice = in.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter item:");
                Coin item = in.nextInt();
                if (bag.add(item)) {
                    System.out.println("Item " + item + " is added successfully to the bag");
                }
                break;
```

On the `Coin item = in.next();` I am getting an error `Incompatibile types: String cannot be converted to Int`. What I am asking is what do I have to write so that it is converted that way the user can input an integer value so that it brings them to their selected option in the list.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: So what do you think (or what does Javadoc say)  `nextInt()` does return? An `Integer` right? Is an `Integer` a `Coin`? What do you think?

Comment: first of all, the pasted code lists the command as `Coin item = in.nextInt();` and that will cause a different "Incompatibile types" error . second, the error is quite clear, the return type from `in.nextInt();` and from `in.next();` are not compatible with the left hand of the assignment

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take in an integer (nextInt()) and assign it to Coin. They are two different data types.

I suggest you read up on the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).